# Problemas envio/recibir email en el extranjero ¿Es problema del dominio o de las redes?

Tags: email, dominio, outlook

Soy el administrador de un dominio (www.midominio.com) que está alojado en un hosting español. El caso es que uno de los clientes que utiliza el correo nombrecliente@midominio.com no pudo enviar un email desde una ciudad de Canadá. No funcionaba ni el correo en el móvil ni el correo a través de Outlook.

El cliente no recibía ningún mensaje de error, simplemente los emails no se enviaban ni se recibian.

Finalmente tuvo que utilizar la versión web de correo. El caso es que me pide una respuesta detallada. Yo, por su parte se la pedí al servicio técnico del dominio pero su contestación fue:

> Debe ser un problema de red. No tenemos restricciones en ningún país

¿Qué explicación tiene esto?

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no es un tema relacionado con la programación si no más bien con un tema relacionado con los servidores de correo.

Comment: No puedo eliminarla. Si es así yo también voto por cerrarla.

Comment: No la puedes eliminar debido a que hay una respuesta aceptada. Ahora ya no importa, debido a que hay una respuesta que al parecer te ha servido por lo que puede servir a otras personas. Posiblemente sea cerrada como tema no relacionado pero futuros lectores siempre podrán leer la pregunta y respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta que te dio el servicio técnico es la correcta. Lo que puedes contestar al cliente sería:

"Estimado Cliente

Solicitamos la revisión de su caso al servicio técnico y nuestro servicio se mantuvo activo de forma normal.

- Por favor recuerde mantener actualizados todos los parches de su S.O.
- Actualización del APP de su celular con las últimas versiones
- Chequear con su proveedor de internet su conectividad.

Saludos